# Automate registering Yammer Application

Tags: sharepoint-2013, yammer

Can we automate the process of registering a yammer application? By yammer application, i mean  the application with Client Code, secret code and token to access yammer data using REST API.

So that way, if every user in the organization has an app and if yammer app token is stored as a user profile property, it is very likely that users will not hit the rate limits while accessing the Yammer data using the REST API.

Comment: Are you looking for a way around rate-limiting, and your solution is to assign an application token for each user? It won't make a difference if they use their application token or their oauth token, they'll still be subjected to rate-limiting.

Comment: Thanks michaelh for ur comments. My understanding is it does. If there are 20 users posting reply at same time, with one single token, some of these are going to get that rate limit error. But if each of the user have their own application token, and post reply same time as others, they will not get the rate limit erorr as each of the request would be their first request.

"API calls are subject to rate limiting. Rate limits are per user per app." - from Yammer documentation.

Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: This is wrong. Your app token is used to authenticate the app. Actions taken on behalf of your users, after they have logged on to Yammer and received an OAUTH token, will be taken on behalf of each user. The important thing to do is to make sure that the users' OAUTH tokens are used when you need to make an action against Yammer as that user. You should have one app, one app token, and each user will use your app, your app will connect to Yammer, then your users will use their own tokens to perform actions against Yammer.